# How to store tkinter button widgets in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter, widget

The two goals of my program: #1 copy notes to the clipboard after clicking a button; and #2 make the button widgets persist through restart of the program. (This post will focus solely on goal number 1) The buttons are populated as expected, but the command does not work properly (No Errors though). I've tried other clipboard modules such as pyperclip with no luck. Apologies if this was hard to follow, I just started to learn python as my first programming language last week.

I would like to know how I would go about making the buttons copy their corresponding notes to the clipboard.

```
from tkinter import *
import json

root = Tk()
root.title("CopyNotes")
root.geometry()

json_file = open("dictionary.json", encoding="utf-8")
mynotes = json.load(json_file)

for keys in mynotes:
    btnz = Button(root, text=mynotes[keys][0], font="Helvetica 10 bold", bg="silver", command=root.clipboard_append(mynotes[keys][1]), height=2, width=13).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

root.mainloop()
```

So just to be clear, the issue I'm trying to solve is the button command not working properly. First time any buttons are pressed it copies 'button1notebutton2notebutton3note'and stops working at all after that.
The effect I want the first button to achieve: root.clipboard_append(button1note)
and so on for the rest..

After I figure out how to do this, I plan on accepting user input to add their own buttons by adding to the dictionary.
Edit: Fixed the clipboard issue -

```
    mynotes = pickle.load(open("note.p", "rb"))
    print(mynotes)
    for keys in mynotes:
        thenotes = mynotes[keys][1]
        mybtnz = Button(ctowin, text=mynotes[keys][0], font="Helvetica 10 bold", bg="silver",
                                command=lambda thenotes=thenotes: pyperclip.copy(thenotes), height=2, width=13)\
            .pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

[Button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHsxM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use json as you are not working with a JSON object but a python dictionary.

Here is your code refactored to populate the app with 3 buttons;

[**UPDATED**] Although you will need to completely refactor your code because your `for` loop is populating the clipboard with everything in your dictionary immediately.

```
from tkinter import *
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

db = TinyDB('clipboard.json')

root = Tk()
root.title("CopyNotes")
root.geometry()

mynotes = {
    "B1": ["button1label","button1note"], 
    "B2":["button2label","button2note"], 
    "B3":["button3label","button3note"]
}

def cp_to_cb_and_db(note, key):
    root.clipboard_append(note[key][1])
    print('[+] Adding note: {} to clipboard.'.format(note))
    db.insert({key: note})


for key in mynotes:
    btnz = Button(
        root, 
        text=mynotes[key][0], 
        font="Helvetica 10 bold", 
        bg="silver", 
        command=cp_to_cb_and_db(mynotes, key), 
        height=2, 
        width=13).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Jack I'll keep that in mind! I've updated my code on here to reflect those changes and make it easier for people to see. I'll still have to use an external file but for the purposes of this post that's irrelevant. Anyway, the problem that lies in command=root.clipboard_append(mynotes[keys][1]) still persists. Have any ideas or workaround for that? Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't really change your question because now it works and your asking why it doesn't work.. others will go to the accepted answer to see the correct way to do it. It would be more helpful to others to see your wrong code and then see the correct code in an accepted answer, please accept my answer if it helped and you think it will help others

Comment: you are only storing the values of `mynotes` in the clipboard in memory (ram) so when the code finishes the values are lost, will need a way to persist the data, maybe in a flat file database or even a text file

Comment: I will update my answer shortly with an example of how you can do that..

Comment: updated... it will now store data in a flat database file in a json format but you access the data with `Query()` class. try the docs - https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - TinyDB is actually quite powerful and easy to use

Comment: if my answer has helped you please accept my answer so others can see tht the answer works. thanks